# No ClassTag available for MyClass.this.T for an abstract type

Tags: scala, type-erasure, type-parameter, type-members

This works well

```
class MyClass[T<: Actor: ClassTag] extends Actor {
  //....
}
```

but this doesn't due to the error `No ClassTag available for MyClass.this.T`

```
class MyClass extends Actor {
  type T<: Actor
  //...
}
```

even when do the following:

```
class MyClass extends Actor {
  type T<: Actor: ClassTag //this doesn't even compile
  //...
}
```

How do I use an abstract `type` and get rid of the error?

Answer (score 8):

```
class M[A <: B: C]
```

is short for

```
class M[A <: B](implicit c: C[A])
```

Therefore, if you move `A` to an abstract type member, you would have to write something like

```
abstract class M {
  type A <: B
  implicit protected def c: C[A]
}
```

and require anyone implementing `M` to provide such a *value* `c`. If you want `M` non-abstract, you must require a constructor value parameter of type `C[A]`, which in turn means that type `A` must be constructor type parameter...

---

**Edit** to answer the comments: The notation `A : C` *is defined* as expanding to an implicit value parameter of type `C[A]`. There `C` is called context bound, and it can be understood as asking for a type class `C[_]` for type `A`. If you *implement* `M` you do not need to repeat the `implicit` modifier. Why is it there? Let me give you an example using a well-known type class `Ordering`:

```
 abstract class Foo {
   type A
   implicit protected def ord: Ordering[A]

   protected def seq: Seq[A]

   def range: (A, A) = {
     val xs = seq
     xs.min -> xs.max
   }
 }
```

If you removed `implicit`, you would have to change the calls to `xs.min` and `xs.max` which require an implicit `Ordering`.

```
object Bar extends Foo {
  type A = Int
  val seq = List(8, 34, 5, 21, 3, 13)
  val ord = Ordering.Int  // don't need to repeat `implicit`
}

Bar.range // (3, 34)
```

Here, `Bar` shows how you provide the implicit value parameter. This would be the same for `ClassTag`:

```
trait MyClass {
  type A
  implicit def tag: reflect.ClassTag[A]
}

object StringClass extends MyClass {
  type A = String
  // type String is statically known, thus compiler gives us this:
  val tag = reflect.classTag[String]
}
```

If your child class is *generic again*, you will need to pass on the responsibility for providing a class tag:

```
class GenericClass[A1](implicit val tag: reflect.ClassTag[A1]) {
  type A = A1
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I played around with it a bit, and two questions arose: 1) Why is method `c` in `M` *implicit*: ? Isn't a  non-implicit method equivalent to the preceding two versions using parametrized types? 2) In the special case of a `ClassTag` a constructor value is not required (I replaced it with `override val c = classTag[...]` in the class). Isn't this generally possible?

Comment: how do I provide the implementation of `c: ClassTag` in the child classes? What should it look like?

Comment: it seems there is redundant repetition in `object StringClass extends MyClass` - type A = `String` and val tag = reflect.classTag[`String`]? Can I avoid this?

Comment: Could you please show me an example of **If you want M non-abstract, you must require a constructor value parameter of type C[A], which in turn means that type A must be constructor type parameter**?

Comment: @Alex you either know type `A` statically (example `StringClass`), or you don't and it remains generic. Then any concrete class will need to get the class tag via a constructor (example `GenericClass`), so you end up more or less at the point where you departed from. Regarding your first comment: Type parameters are erased at runtime, that's why you have tags in the first place, so they are _not_ redundant. If you don't use Arrays, though, you will pretty seldomly need them.